# Позиция второго блока. Как сделать динамичным?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Хочу сделать parallax эффект. Все сделал. Отлично работает. Но(!), дело такое:

У меня 2 блока:

```
#part1 {
height: 100%;
min-width: 700px;
max-height: 900px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url('img/bg.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
z-index: 1;
}

#part2 {
z-index: 7;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: yellow;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
}
```

При загрузке страницы - все нормально. Но при resize вторая часть опускается на 50% ниже. Т.е Идет первая часть + пустота(~50%) + вторая часть. При перезагрузке страницы - все сидит на свои места.

**Вопрос**: Как сделать, чтобы при resize данный блок шел сразу после первого?

Я использовал javascript - resize event, вычислял высоту первого блока и ставил top: part1_height. Не помогло.

Comment: а чем вам помочь, если за три года вы так и не научились вопросы задавать. пример полный с разметкой в студию. (fiddle, plunker, jsbin)

Comment: а мне все 300 строчек сюда вам показать??? Имеются 2 части. Код выше. При изменении разрешения окна, второй опускается на 50% ниже, образуется пропасть. Что вам нужно то еще знать?

Comment: выделить проблему и показать. нет разметки - нет решения (кроме того ещё и потому, что паралаксом называют множество разных вещей),  вообще это вам надо а не нам.

[вот ваш код](http://jsfiddle.net/vh6jW/) где тут проблема с паралаксом ума не приложу.

Comment: О_о зачем столько извращений, вот простой [пример][1]


  [1]: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=1565